# While installing Kubuntu on external HDD GRUB installs to my main disk instead of the HDD even though i set it to install the my external disk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive

I'm installing the latest version of Kubuntu and the install process goes fine. I am installing int on a 160gb HDD. during the install, I select the bootloader to install to /dev/sda, but then I see the boot loader in my Lenovo boot menu even when the drive is unplugged. I am running windows 10 as my main OS. could anyone tell me or point me to an article or video about how to fix this or do it properly maybe I am doing something wrong?

Output of : `mount | grep sda` - runs without error, no output.
Output of : `ls /etc/default/grub` - `/etc/defaut/grub`
Output of : `ls /boot` - `config-5.4.0-26-generic  initrd.img.old  memtest86+_multiboot.bin     vmlinuz.old
grub                     memtest86+.bin  System.map-5.4.0-26-generic
initrd.img               memtest86+.elf  vmlinuz`

Output of : `ls /boot/grub` - `gfxblacklist.txt  grubenv  unicode.pf2`

Output of : `mount | grep ^\/dev` (not in chroot) - `/dev/sdb1 on /cdrom type vfat (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)`

Answer (score 0):

Now, I guess it's better to start ground up.
I took my time to write this all down, so please read this and try to understand every step.

- All actions should be conducted from Linux liveUSB, no windows involved or things will get even more complicated.
- Partitioning. Generally your Linux drive looks like this:

  / root partition ext4 - typically sda1 (sdb1 etc.), i.e. first primary partition.
  swap - swap partition - typically sda5, in extended partition space (often optional, if you have a lot of ram and not too much load).

GRUB boot loader goes in `/boot` folder of root partition, you can find folder "grub" there.

- All actions you do, are going to happen with root partition mounted. This means, that root partition should be mounted before you install grub or make any actions.
- On liveUSB we must mount our external drive to some folder, say `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`. This folder will be root of our new system.
- Now, there are certain folders that are created and altered dynamically during system boot and run. We need liveUSB so to have access to this folders we need to mount them to our external drive root location before we chroot. Because there will be no access to folders outside chroot afterwards.

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev

sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc

- Chroot to our root, like `chroot /mnt /bin/bash`. Here we have system booted from liveUSB, but all commands are executed like it was booted from external hard drive we want system on.
- At this point we should have all files in place, we just want to install grub. This step is already completed as it shows menu at system startup.
- Issue is that grub has wrong OS path/drive, so when you try to boot it doesn't start. There are two ways to cure this.

Easy one: to run upate-grub2 and hope it recreate boot config in correct way. I could fail because some BIOS alter drive order and it alters sda,sdb,sdc,etc.. naming.

Hard way is to edit grub config manually, but for this task you should do a little bit reading concerning grub config and grub console.

Comment: I understand the OP's frustration, because it's a poor choice by *Ubuntu to display the system disk as default for installing grub. You've got a dropdown menu to choose from, but your system disk is pre-selected, and if you're not careful, you can install grub on it even though you didn't want to.

Comment: so should i not install the system and flash the iso to the HDD

Comment: or install the system to the HDD, the create a /mnt directory and mount the root partition to there and install grub on the root partition (and then unmount the root partition)

Comment: I'll edit answer above

Comment: Ill try this in some time and let you know how it went. Thank you for your help

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. Is there any other information that you might need in order to better answer my question

Comment: 1. Check your destination drive has bootable flag.
2. See what output grub gave you during install.

Comment: UPDATE: I managed to make it appear in the boot menu of my laptop following this tutorial: https://www.dionysopoulos.me/making-a-portable-full-installation-of-ubuntu-on-a-usb-hdd.html, but when I click on it it says boot failed and brings me back to windows. Any help?

Comment: Do I get it right?
1. You have installed grub to external hard drive.
2. BIOS points to that drive as bootable.
3. When you boot it, GRUB runs, but doesn't boot linux, right?

Comment: And if you unplug external drive windows boots without problem?

Comment: 1. Yes 2. I think so. It appears on the BIOS boot menu. 3. No. Nothing happens, it just says that the drive failed to boot. I do not see the GRUB screen.

Comment: and yes, windows boots fine without it

Comment: Ok, then you installed grub on external hdd, but linux points to wrong drive. It's manageable. Could you please boot into linux? live usb will do.

Comment: I am now running kubuntu live 20.04 on my laptop. What now, and sorry for the wait

Comment: mount external drive, chroot and update-grub2

Comment: Could you maybe post the commands needed to do that

Comment: Also, should I mount the whole drive or the partition to which i have installed GRUB

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd - here's good description.

Comment: Thank you for that, but there seem to be no grub files or no grub directory in /mnt/boot

Comment: so should i chroot into there and install grub from your command above or the one in the link I posted earlier and then run sudo update-grub

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 if you could also say why I do not see a grub directory even though I installed it?

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 UPDATE: it says that it cannot find the path to grub.cfg, however, I have found the file. it is in /dev/sda4 which is my ESP partition and the path on windows shows up as D:\EFI\BOOT\grub.cfg. In the folder, there are also some other .efi files and a Microsoft excel file. Did I incorrectly install GRUB? and what should I do about this?

Comment: I think this needs a bit of explaination. I'll edit post above.

Comment: Thank you. I will test in a bit. However, there is one clarification I would like to make. Should I mount ONLY my root partition or also my EFI system partiton

Comment: Could you please boot in linux and `sudo fdisk -l`? You should have no EFI partition on external drive.

Comment: /dev/sda1       146905088 165779455  18874368    9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2       165781502 312580095 146798594   70G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda3            2048 145881087 145879040 69.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4  *    145881088 146905087   1024000  500M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

Comment: /dev/sda4 is an EFI partition while /dev/sda3 is my root partition

Comment: I see. In your case you should mount: `/dev/sda3 to /` and `/dev/sda4 to /boot` after mounting root

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 So for clarification, do `sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt` followed by `sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt/boot` ?

Comment: Yes.
If you don't mind, I'd recommend you to view a quick Linux tutorial. I know it's a bit boring, but believe me, it will make your work in Linux significantly easier.

Comment: This is the output: `root@kubuntu:/# sudo update-grub2
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 268: cannot create /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new: Directory nonexistent`

Comment: Another piece of info that may help. I managed to run updae-grub2 with no errors by first running `grub-install -d /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi/ --removable /dev/sda` and immediately after `sudo update-grub2` but the boot still failed.

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 is that the right command? my external disk is /dev/sda and i had everything mounted

Comment: Add all output to initial post.
1. `mount | grep sda`
2. `ls /etc/default/grub`
3. `ls /boot`

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 have edited post

Comment: good, now `ls /boot/grub`, after pasting answer select it and use  { } icon to format it as code. It will be much more readable. Also just `mount | grep ^\/dev` output.

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 done

Comment: `exit` - this exits chroot, `mount | grep ^\/dev`

Comment: i will be able to do this in 30 minutes

Comment: no rush, take your time.

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 Thank you for waiting. I was not in chroot

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 none of the outputs i posted, unless specified otherwise, were run from a chroot environment

Comment: you need to run command outside chroot

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 I am not running the command in chroot. I copy and pasted the command so that it looks like this: `kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ mount | grep ^\/dev` and the output is above. None of my HDD's partitions are mounted either

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 even without the drive plugged in the output is the same

Comment: let's see just mount, with no grep, but drive should be connected

Comment: For `mount | ^\/dev` i get no such file or directory

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 just mount gives `sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=3982952k,nr_inodes=995738,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=805836k,mode=755)
/dev/sdb1 on /cdrom type vfat (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)`

Comment: followed by `/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
/cow on / type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/filesystem.squashfs,upperdir=/cow/upper,workdir=/cow/work)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)`

Comment: and `cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)`

Comment: `cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup `

Comment: This needs clarification: `mount` - gives list of mounted drives, "|" redirects output of mount to another command, "grep  ^\/dev" filters output of mount with " ^\/dev" mask. There is no point in running just mask with no grep. On the other hand, just "mount" will list all mounted drives.

Comment: `cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=28,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=20920)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M`

Comment: So what do you need?

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 what outputs do you require?

Comment: `ls /dev/sd[abcd]*`

Comment: `/dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1  /dev/sdc  /dev/sdc1  /dev/sdc2  /dev/sdc3  /dev/sdc4  /dev/sdc5`

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc`

Comment: `Disk /dev/sdc: 149.5 GiB, 160041885696 bytes, 312581808 sectors
Disk model: HTS545016B9A300 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xce41a31c

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1       146905088 165779455  18874368    9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdc2       165781502 312580095 146798594   70G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdc3            2048 145881087 145879040 69.6G 83 Linux`

Comment: `/dev/sdc4  *    145881088 146905087   1024000  500M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdc5       165781504 312580095 146798592   70G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Partition table entries are not in disk order.`

Comment: `mount /dev/sdc3 /mnt`, `mkdir /mnt/boot/efi`, `mount /dev/sdc4 /mnt/boot/efi`, `ls /mnt/boot/efi`

Comment: Fisr command runs fine, but then `root@kubuntu:~# mkdir /mnt/boot/efi
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot/efi’: File exists`

Comment: no problem, just mount efi parition there and check contents.

Comment: After mounting /dev/sdc4, `root@kubuntu:~# ls /mnt/boot/efi
'$RECYCLE.BIN'   EFI   grub  'System Volume Information'`

Comment: Well... `ls /mnt/boot`

Comment: `config-5.4.0-26-generic  initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic  memtest86+_multiboot.bin
efi                      initrd.img.old               System.map-5.4.0-26-generic
grub                     memtest86+.bin               vmlinuz
initrd.img               memtest86+.elf               vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic
`

Comment: Looks like grub installed wrong way

Comment: `grub-mkconfig -o /mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, `ls /mnt/boot/grub/*.cfg`

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 1st command returns `/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.`, second returns `/mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: Now copypaste first error to google and see if there is a solution.

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 i found a workaround but then it returns : `/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 268: cannot create /mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new: Directory nonexistent` also I had to run the command from chroot : https://askubuntu.com/questions/254491/failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow  3rd solution

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 what should i run now?

Comment: There will be no `/mnt/boot/grub` when run from chroot. 
From chroot you should specify `/boot/grub`

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 It ran without any problems or errors. What now?

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 This is the output: `Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (20.04) on /dev/sda3
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done`

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 after running the command I tried booting it from the menu (without unmounting anything) and it failed to boot again.

Comment: `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: I will do this tomorrow and let you know how it went

Comment: `if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${initrdfail}" = 2 ]; then
   set initrdfail=
elif [ "${initrdfail}" = 1 ]; then
   set next_entry="${prev_entry}"
   set prev_entry=
   save_env prev_entry
   if [ "${next_entry}" ]; then
      set initrdfail=2
   fi
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi`

Comment: `if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi`

Comment: `}
function initrdfail {
    if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -n "${partuuid}" ]; then
      if [ -z "${initrdfail}" ]; then
        set initrdfail=1
        if [ -n "${boot_once}" ]; then
          set prev_entry="${default}"
          save_env prev_entry
        fi
      fi
      save_env initrdfail
    fi; fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}`

Comment: `function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if loadfont unicode ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi`

Comment: `terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
#set_background_image "images/tile.png";`

Comment: `set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 0,0,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
        set gfxpayload="${1}"
        if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
                set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
        else
                set vt_handoff=
        fi
}`

Comment: `if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###`

Comment: `### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (20.04) (on /dev/sda3)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c' {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos3'`

Comment: ` if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3  3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic root=UUID=3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic
}
`

Comment: `submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (20.04) (on /dev/sda3)' $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-advanced-3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu (on /dev/sda3)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic--3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c' {
                insmod part_msdos
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,msdos3'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root `

Comment: `--hint-bios=hd0,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3  3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c
                fi
                linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic root=UUID=3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
                initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic
        }`

Comment: `        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-26-generic (on /dev/sda3)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic--3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c' {
                insmod part_msdos
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,msdos3'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3  3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c
                else`

Comment: ` fi
                linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic root=UUID=3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
                initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic
        }`

Comment: `--hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3  3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c   else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c
                fi
                linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic root=UUID=3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c ro recovery nomodeset
                initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic
        }
}
--hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3  3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c
                else`

Comment: `--hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3  3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c
                fi
                linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic root=UUID=3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c ro recovery nomodeset
                initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic
        }
}`

Comment: `set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
        fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###`

Comment: `### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;`

Comment: `fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
`

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 sorry for the mass copy-and-pasting but i did not know what you wanted from it, and i had to run it chrooted to /mnt where i mounted my efi partition.

Comment: use `blkid` command on /dev/sdc3 to confirm that `--hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3 3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c else search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c fi linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic root=UUID=3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c ro recovery nomodeset initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic` here is right root partition.

Comment: /dev/sdc3 is my root partition I am SURE of that. The mount point is /

Comment: Yes, at the same time `root=UUID=3f05bc18-8cb3-47fe-a2ae-1ff3f31fcb2c` could point wrong UUID (which is unlikely, but still).

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 that IS the UUID of my root partition

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 anyway what can I do next

Comment: there's a hard part. Point is: boot from external hdd into grub. Then `e` to edit config and try to boot manually setting boot drive. Once system boots from external hard drive, just `update-grub2` will fix everything (most of the time). I recommend to have another PC around to read documentation while experimenting.

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 I am not sure how to do that; could you outline the steps or send me a link to the procedure that describes it

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 maybe a blog post or a forum post or something

Comment: This could help
https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux/

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 i think you misunderstand the problem. I do not see a the GRUB shell. The drive simply does not boot.

Comment: Have you setup BIOS to boot UEFI? Whole EFI boot loader situation seems a bit over complicated. 
Why won't try to setup BIOS for legacy boot, and then set /dev/sda3 partition bootable and install there grub?

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 I can not change my BIOS to legacy. I have tried this and it does not work. My BIOS can only boot UEFI.

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 i think i might have a solution. I found an old laptop and I can unplug the internal HDD and install it from live USB, forcing it to install on my external drive

Comment: Glad to hear that.